# Javascript what does <. undefined in console after console.log()

Tags: javascript, console.log

Below is a simple code

```
var stop = true;
console.log(stop);
```

In console is show like this:

```
   true  
<. undefined  // what this undefined, is it some reference.
```

I am wondering what is `undefined`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/07avLoc9/ .. no? http://prntscr.com/79z9dp

Comment: Is it in **node.js** console?

Comment: @N.Molderf it is browser inspect element console

Comment: this is also the case for an assignment `var x = 1` results into `<. undefined`

Comment: @briosheje past this code in your browser console

Comment: @ozil: everything written in the browser console logs undefined. you can also write "hello" that it will, I think that is related to the browser's console rather than javascript itself.

Answer (score 1):

Every statement in JavaScript returns something.

When you enter `console.log(true),` true will be printed out and `undefined` will be returned.

`undefined` is one of the seven types in JavaScript that means something has been declared but not assigned a value.

`undefined` is the return value of `console.log` statements.

Answer (score 1):

It's the return value of the `console.log` function.
The `true` that you see is a side-effect.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. what do you mean by "side-effect"?

Comment: I'd be glad to know what part of it doesn't make sense. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29

Comment: This answer is actually correct. `console.log` returns `undefined`

Comment: Your answer lacks any description. "Side-effect" is a very general term, and it is not particularly clear what you mean by that. At least add that last link to the actual answer for more clarification.